# How to connect specific vertices from different objects in order to simulate as one?

Tags: cloth-simulation

This is a tough nut to crack, I´ve been trying to simulate a cloth which in every corner has a circular cut with a "metal clamp" in order for the cloth to be connected to a static fixture. However when trying to simulate, what happens is the cloth disconnects from the metal clamp and falls to the floor. Now, the metal clamp itself gives perfect physics with the static fixture. All that is missing would be the cloth being connected to the metal clamp "as one".

Let me add that the cloth and the metal clamp were once connected but were disconnected due to wanting the clamp to have more solid properties.

I really want to get this to work be it connected by vertices or going in with an alternate approach. It´s been a really daunting task to try and figure this thing out, I hope you guys can give me some insight.

I think the image will give you a better idea.

This screenshot is just a few seconds into the falling simulation, so that you can better see the separated parts.

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you tried pinning the vertices that make the hole where the ring should be?

Comment: I have tried that, but the result I get is that the the pinned ring becomes fully static.

Comment: You do want the edges of the cloth that connect to the ring to be static. I can't test it now, but it seems to me that what you need is to create a set of vertex groups on the cloth for every metal ring. Then use hooks to have those vertex groups follow the movement/placement of the metal rings. The metal rings should then be a rigid body that interacts with the larger rings from where the whole curtain hangs.

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html

Comment: To my surprise that did the job, all I did before was go solely with either hooks alone or vertex pinning. Is there a way to mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Comments are not answers, but please do write an answer to your own question. Please detail the steps you took to solve the issue. It might help others that run into the same situation. : )